# ExtJS Grid with Remote Buffered Store Fails to Render First Page

Tags: extjs, extjs4

ExtJS version: 4.1.0

I have an infinite-scrolling grid with remote buffered store declared as follows:

```
Ext.define('App.store.UserGridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 30,
    leadingBufferZone:60,
    trailingBufferZone:60,
    scrollToLoadBuffer:20,
    numFromEdge:20,
    clearOnPageLoad:false,

    isSortable: true,
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'Service/data',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            noCache: true,
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

On a page with a few pages of rows, when a user scrolls down all the way and then back up to page 1, the grid re-renders all pages except for page 1 (for which it just shows blank space).

The store appears to correctly fire a query to my backend service and the service returns the correct data. However, the data is not rendered on the grid.

Any pointers to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem went away after I set pageSize to a much larger number (300). It probably happened because the store couldn't handle too many AJAX calls due to the low pageSize (30).

Comment: Note that a buffered store is meant for very large data sets. If you're requesting small amounts of pages it's not really appropriate.

Comment: This is well worth noting- although it is a failure of Ext JS that a buffered grid cannot handle consistently page sizes <100.